# Recieveing error when calling api request in NextJs "banner.map is not a function"

Tags: javascript, api, next.js

so I followed a tutorial that was fairly simple and was just showing how to request data from an API and display it. But when I have gone to view the page in my project NextJs returns and error "banner.map is not a function" I've put my code bellow any help would be greatly appreciated. The API call is "https://fortnite-api.com/v1/banners" which returns an array of objects.

```
    export const getStaticProps = async () => {

    const res = await fetch('https://fortnite-api.com/v1/banners');
    const data = await res.json();

    return {
        props: { banners: data}
    }

}

const FortniteApi = ({ banners }) => {
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Fortnite Api</h1>
            {banners.map(banner => (
                <div key={banner.id}>
                    <a>
                        <h3>{banner.name}</h3>
                    </a>
                </div>
            ))}
        </div>
    )
}

export default FortniteApi
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### **You will need to access another object `data` inside:**

```
return {
  props: { banners: data },
};
```

**TO**

```
return {
  props: { banners: data.data },
};
```

Comment: Would you believe I was thinking that lol. Thanks a lot appreciate it!

Comment: Haha, It's not redundant to check the response first.

Comment: You can also use a different syntax like this to access the nested data object.
props: { banners: {data} }

Comment: This may be asking to much but is there a way to limit how much of that data I can request? Say I only request from 0 to 20 out of the array.

Comment: That depends on the endpoint if they support that query or not. In your case, It's not as I checked here: https://dash.fortnite-api.com/

Comment: But you can always "slice down" your response to only take the first 20th.

Comment: If you find this helpful, you could mark this as `accepted` for others who need it. And it also means a lot for contributions like me.

Comment: Will do, would anyone know how to add headers into the code above?

Comment: What headers are you talking about?

Comment: A different API I wanted to test needs to have an auth header, But I ain't sure how to go about it.

Comment: Ah, That's a different context, could you please create another question for that? Leave the link here see if I can help

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69089683/axios-api-request-in-nextjs-returning-cannot-read-property-of-map-of-undefined - Different question but if you any idea that'd be huge, I've tried to use axios before but couldn't work it, so I thought I'd give it a go to then run into this.

Comment: Sure, I'll take a look at that