# Axios api request in NextJs returning cannot read property of 'map' of undefined

Tags: javascript, axios, next.js

Okay so I'm trying to return data from this API endpoint https://fortnite-api.com/v2/cosmetics/br using axios is NextJs but Next keeps returning the error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined" Any ideas on how to fix?

```
import axios from "axios"

const CosmeticsApi = ({cosmetics}) => {
  return (
    <div>
      {cosmetics.map(cosmetic =>(
        <div key={cosmetic.id}>
          <h4>{cosmetic.name}</h4>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  )
}

CosmeticsApi.getInitalProps = async ctx => {
  try {
    const res = await axios.get('https://fortnite-api.com/v2/cosmetics/br');
    const cosmetics = res.data;
    return { cosmetics };
  } catch (error) {
    return {error};
  };
};

export default CosmeticsApi;
```

Comment: Probably because `axios.get` is asynchronous? so you need to wait for the result

Comment: The initial props will be undefined at the first load time, so you need some loading implementation until cosmetics are not undefined.

const CosmeticsApi = ({cosmetics}) => {
  return (
    <div>
      {cosmetics?.map(cosmetic =>(
        <div key={cosmetic.id}>
          <h4>{cosmetic.name}</h4>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  )
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### **Like the previous question, you will need to access another layer of data:**

And it's `getInitialProps` not `getInitalProps`.. Oh dear, you've got me awhile.

```
CosmeticsApi.getInitialProps = async ctx => {
  try {
    const res = await axios.get('https://fortnite-api.com/v2/cosmetics/br');
    const cosmetics = res.data.data;  // <-- Access one more data object here
    return { cosmetics };
  } catch (error) {
    return {error};
  };
};
```

**And you might want to check if the array exists before mapping it:**

```
const CosmeticsApi = ({cosmetics}) => {
  return (
    <div>
      {cosmetics && cosmetics.map(cosmetic =>(
        <div key={cosmetic.id}>
          <h4>{cosmetic.name}</h4>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  )
}
```

**Working Example:**

[image: Edit next.js-getInitialProps-redux (forked)]

Comment: Okay both of these fixes corrects the error but then nothing is shown? It might possibly just be me being stupid here

Comment: Yeah, I Just check with the API URL, it needs to access another data layer like your previous question. I updated my answer.

Comment: Sorry I feel this is annoying BUT I hugely appreciate all the help. I tried this and seemingly the page is still blank, it's like its not updating once it's finished the initial load

Comment: Hmmm. Let me try it on an actual Nextjs app

Comment: Got ya! It's `getInitialProps` not `getInitalProps`. Almost took me the whole night buddy.

Comment: Omg I can't be that dumb. Thank you and yes the sandbox works! On my project it's working too. I feel so bad for that one but huge thanks to you!

Comment: No problem, Dude! My eyes now get to the next level already :D

Comment: Haha have a rest now, your a legend for all that!

Comment: It's okay dude, See you around!

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the issue.

It occurred because I broke a simple rule.

According to the next.js [document](https://github.com/zeit/next.js#fetching-data-and-component-lifecycle), there is a note saying

**Note: getInitialProps can not be used in children components. Only in pages.**

So when I fetched that data at index.js, it successfully gets the data I want to have.

Thought I could use getInitialProps in any components just like componentDidMount.

That was a problem.

Comment: This is a page though and not a component, directory is as follows (project folder/src/pages/cosmetic/index.jsx

Comment: Okay, then please try with `fetch` instead of `axios`.